# FluentValidation doing validation at the wrong time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I have FluentValidation setup on my MVC website.  One of my objects has a validation check that uses the Must command to call a function:

```
RuleFor(m => m).Must(m => reimbursementMonthsRequired(m)).WithMessage("Wrong!").WithName("ReimbursementStartMonth");
```

The reimbursementMonthsRequired function checks a value on the object and a collection under the object to determine validity.

I have a Post method that accepts a list of values which is used to update that collection:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddGrant(Grant item, List<byte> reimbursementMonths)
{
  item.UpdateReimbusementMonths(Database, reimbursementMonths);
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {     
    Database.Grants.Add(item);
    Database.SaveChanges();
    ...
```

The problem I'm having is that in this function, the validation check is called before UpdateReimbusementMonths is called.  So the data I need to be there for the validation check to work right is not there yet.  The odd thing is, is that in my Edit function, the validation happens after I call UpdateReimbursementMonths, so it works correctly.  This is what that is doing:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditGrant(int id, List<byte> reimbursementMonths)
{
  var item = Database.Grants.Find(id);
  item.UpdateReimbusementMonths(Database, reimbursementMonths);
  TryUpdateModel(item);
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  ...
```

So how do I get my Add function to do validation at the proper time - being after the function call to update the collection?  It seems that if I could re-run the validation checks after that function call, that would work.

Comment: validation you mentioned, is that for Grant object?

Comment: Not the best solution...but how about you Remove the key from ModelState (using ModelState.Remove) before the ModelState.IsValid? Then you can add your grants and Add the key back to the ModelState and validate it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it works to have the AddGrant method do something similar to EditGrant.  Instead of taking a Grant object as a method parameter I did this:

```
public ActionResult AddGrant(List<byte> reimbursementMonths)
{      
  var item = new Grant();
  item.UpdateReimbusementMonths(Database, reimbursementMonths);
  TryUpdateModel(item);

  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {     
    ...
```

Fortunately I do not use any values from the Grant object in the UpdateReimbusementMonths method.  If I did I'd have to figure something else out because apparently TryUpdateModel triggers the validation process.

Answer (score 0):

It is working according to [documentation](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc)

In AddGrant method you are posting Grant object so it does do validation after auto binding before it executes any code in your action method.

-> You either have to update Grant with reimbursements before posting or remove the fluent validation and do this validation manually in the action method.

-> Another option is writing a custom `Validator Interceptors` and update Grant item with Reimbursements in `BeforeMvcValidation` method. ( this may be a hack and not be ideal to do)